# Stack problems when copying from array to another in Fortran?

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, intel-fortran

If I am doing the following copy in Fortran

```
 arr(i1:i2) = u(1:n)
```

where `SIZE(arr(i1:i2)) == SIZE(u(1:n))` and the size is relative big, e.g 2M elements of double precision.

If variable `arr` is a pointer alias to another allocatable array.  Would Fortran use the stack or heap memory to handle the copy assignment.?

If it is using the stack, is there any specific reason for that choice.?

How could one possibly avoid the compiler using the stack to not get a stackoverflow, without having to run `ulimit -s unlimited` on the Linux terminal.?

Comment: _If it walks like a duck_ ....  There is insufficient information (i.e., code) to make any guess concerning the explanation for using stack space.

Comment: I was wondering whether a copy like the shown will include the use of the stack memory

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, I checked both sizes `SIZE(arr(i1:i2))` & `SIZE(u(1:n))`. Both give same integer. I also find it strange that when I set my stack size to unlimited, it works.

Comment: If the arrays are pointers (and not allocatable), the compiler assumes there might be overlap and will use a temp. IIRC, current ifort versions default to dynamic allocation of array temps, but if you have an older version, try adding -heap-arrays to the compile.

Comment: Thank you @SteveLionel. It is a pointer to a some memory infact. The code in general is difficult to reproduce in a simplified manner. (I am still trying).

The pointer itself comes from a MPI API which returns me a pointer with a size to some shared window. I checked that the size of the pointer between i1 and i2 is equal to the allocatable array I am assigning it to. 

I.e. I did `size(ptr_to_window(i1:i2))` and` size(u(1:n))` Both gave same answer. The fact that the problem disappear after I unlimit my stack size is still mysterious if the application is not using the stack size.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, I will check the assembly code to make sure whether it uses `inte_fast_memcpy`. I am indeed using IFORT 19.0.5 the most recent version.

Comment: If the variables are pointers, then the compiler almost certainly used the stack to make a copy. I was incorrect in thinking that the default was to use the heap - in version 19 it still uses the stack by default. Looking for intel_fast_memcpy won't tell you anything useful.

Comment: Thank you @SteveLionel. That explains my problem! I will try compiling with `-heap-arrays`. I am just curious why a compiler would in this case choose the stack

Comment: If you don't mind inserting your last comment as an answer, Thanks again.

Comment: The main thing you should insert is the actual more complete code into your question. Variale declarations should be an absolute minimum one alwas shows. I don't get why people vote up instead adding another close vote. A question with a problem must have a [mcve].

Comment: It is a rather open question whether fortran uses heap or stack for the operation mentioned, and it was answered. I see that you yourself have answered many questions of this kind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the variables are pointers, then the compiler almost certainly used the stack to create a temp for the copy because it has to assume there may be overlap. It might not be simple overlap either, with discontiguous segments, so doing the copy in different orders doesn't always work.

The semantics of Fortran are that the right side of an assignment is completely evaluated before the left is changed. Unless the compiler can prove that there is no overlap (use of `ALLOCATABLE` will suffice), it will typically use a stack temp for the copy. Intel Fortran has an option `-heap-arrays` that tells it to allocate these temps on the heap, avoiding stack overflow.